# relative layout not filling parent with background color

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to fill the parent with a black background using a relative layout, but it's not working.

This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- this should fill the parent with black but its not filling -->

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why do you have a LinearLayout if you are giving your RelativeLayout match parent ?

Comment: and inside your relative layout add some palette then it will show background colour in your preview.

Comment: removing the linear layout produces the same result

Comment: I added this >>>> android:background="#000"

Comment: Try adding some of the views inside your RelativeLayout and then it will show the background colour

Comment: since it is inside a scrollview this is the solution >>>>  android:fillViewport="true"

Comment: that solved my problem

Comment: add  android:background="#000000" under your scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Put this code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- this should fill the parent with black but its not filling -->


</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a couple of things wrong:

If you want the whole ScrollView to have black background just set it on the ScrollView itself and set it to fill the whole view with fillViewport

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="#000" >
```

RelativeLayouts do not have orientation, that's a LinearLayout attribute

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:orientation="vertical"> <--- WRONG!
```

When you use ScrollView's, you should give it a whole layout child, either Linear or Relative, so that you have more control over the elements inside the ScollView. If you only have a RelativeLayout inside your LinearLayout, just use a RelativeLayout instead.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="#000" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Your elements -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```